# enum has unexpected value on Windows but not Linux

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, enums

I cant get enum this to work properly on Windows. While compiling on linux it returns expected value, but on windows it returns some random number.

```
typedef enum wezly {
    elektrownie1,
    konwencjonalne1,
    niekonwencjonalne1,
    weglowa1,
    jadrowa1,
    sloneczna1,
    wiatrowa1,
    geotermiczna1,
    gazowa1,
    wodna1,
    maremotoryczna1,
    maretermiczna1
};

wezly wybor_wezla(string opcja)
{
    string bb;
    bb = opcja;

    if ((bb.compare("[elektrownie]")==0)||(bb.compare("[ELEKTROWNIE]")==0))
        return elektrownie1;
    else if ((bb.compare("[konwencjonalne]")==0)||(bb.compare("[KONWENCJONALNE]")==0))
        return konwencjonalne1;
    else if ((bb.compare("[gazowa]")==0)||(bb.compare("[GAZOWA]")==0))
        return gazowa1;
    else if ((bb.compare("[wodna]")==0)||(bb.compare("[WODNA]")==0))
        return wodna1;
    // (and so on...)
}

int main()
{

    cout << wybor_wezla("[gazowa]");
}
```

When on linux i get 7, on windows its some random number....

Why can that be ?

Comment: Which number is it returning?

Comment: You did something strange in the `(an so on...)`.  Can you post a self contained, complete, yet minimal example that actually demonstrates the problem?  As in, does the problem still occur if you have fewer `enum` values?  If so, remove them, and test until it occurs reliably with the minimal number of `enum` values (and the minimum sized chained-`if` block)  http://sscce.org/

Comment: it should be 7 but it does weird stuff while on windows

Comment: @user1902400 What is "weird stuff"?

Comment: Why the typedef? It doesn't look your typedef'ing the enum to anything?

Comment: Why is 7 more OK than some other number?

Comment: Also why not just `bb == "[gazowa]"`?

Comment: Here is an example of a minimal version of your code: `enum wezly { gazowa1, };
    
    wezly wybor_wezla(string bb)
    {
      if (bb.compare("[gazowa]")==0)
        return gazowa1;
      else
        return -1;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
      cout << wybor_wezla("[gazowa]");
    }`
    what does it do?

Comment: here is the full example [link](http://ideone.com/O7bDJO)

Comment: I shortened the code so it would show only my problem which is: on linux it runs fine - it returns expected value (7 in this instance)
but on windows it returns random number

Comment: typedef is omitted by compiler so it doesnt matter

Comment: In C, you can do `typedef enum foo { ... } foo;`. In C++, the `typedef` is unnecessary, and the way you've written it is misleading (and possibly illegal).

Comment: @user1902400 A link to a full example is better than incomplete code.  But a good question would involve shortening your code *so that the result still compiles*, and the problem still occurs.  if you don't know what is wrong, you don't know what to shorten -- so shorten and keep the problem occurring until you get something short that exhibits your problem and still compiles (or fails to compile and your problem is you don't know why it does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a final `else` clause:

```
wezly wybor_wezla(string opcja)
{
    if(...)
        return ...;
    else if(...)
        return ...;
    else if(...)
        return ...;
    // No final else!
}
```

When none of the `if` clauses are true, it falls off the end of the function without returning a value, which is *Undefined Behavior*.  In this case, it's returning a garbage value, but worse stuff could happen.

Your first action should be to add a final `else` clause.  This can return a default value, an error code, throw an exception, `abort()`, etc., but it *cannot do nothing*.  If you know the value has to be one of a limited set of things, you could change the final `else if` into just an `else` and assume that if it's not the first `N-1` things, it's the `Nth` thing.

Once you've done that, you need to figure out why your data isn't falling into one of the expected cases and fix that.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually broken here (after looking at [the link you gave in the comments](http://ideone.com/O7bDJO)):

```
  bb=opcja.substr((opcja.find_first_of("[")),(opcja.find_first_of("]"))-1);
```

This results in extracting a string like "[whateve" if the input is "... [whatever] ...".

What I think you mean is:

```
  bb=opcja.substr((opcja.find_first_of("[")),(opcja.find_first_of("]"))-opcja.find_first_of("[")+1);
```

Which results in extracting a string like "[whatever]" from the input.

The original code, given the input "[gazowa]", will compare "[gazow" to various strings, none will match, and the end of the function will be reached without hitting a `return` statement.

This results in undefined behaviour. Hence your result of 7 on linux, and some other value on windows, when `[gazowa]` ought to give you 8.

You also need to do something more sensible to handle the case where none of your strings are matched, i.e. if the end of `wybor_wezla` is reached. What you do in that case is up to you, but as a start I'd at least put a print statement in there so you know when nothing's matched.

Comment: it doesn't change the output, I still get random number like 976868 while compiling this on windows and it is still right on linux

Comment: @user1902400 http://ideone.com/nWNJ7a - seems to work if given one of the strings you check for

Comment: that's my point. It works fine on linux but it fails on windows... that was my only question the whole time

Comment: @user1902400: you need to read this answer more carefully - your Linux runs are not giving you the answer you expect.